# Does the placement of a wall in a 2D grid wall-off a section(s)?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to filter out illegal moves efficiently for a game engine of an old board game. The rules nor the game don't really matter.

The board is a 2D grid with walls around its borders and with every move the player moves one of his pawns and places a wall (horizontal or vertical, of length 2 between any 4 squares) of his own. ***I need to test for every possible wall whether or not it splits the board into unreachable segments***, or rather whether or not a path from a pawn to a goal is blocked. 
*e.g. If there's a wall vertically across the whole middle of the board, it splits the board into two segments; and if there's a pawn on one side and the goal's on the other, that's an illegal wall placement*. I've tried the graph approach with the answers to my previously posted question, but it's pretty slow since I need to generate a move tree and it grows exponentially.

I'm not exactly sure how to approach doing this. I'm guessing processing the board first, then checking for every wall whether it connects to an existing wall and whether that creates new sections. Afterward, check if the crucial squares are in those newly separated sections.

Comment: Are you trying to verify that a wall placed by a human ends up being legal, or building an AI that should consider every wall placement? In the first case, I would simply run an A* path search algorithm and see if it can solve it. For the second you might need something completely different in order to have any kind of acceptable performance (runtime).

Comment: The computer generates all "legal" pawn moves and wall placements. I need a function that is going to find all legal combinations of those moves, in other words, to test this for every one of those walls. I've already tried the graph approach and it's not as good as I'd like

Comment: Do you eliminate all wall placements that don't connect to a side or any other existing wall? If I'm not mistaken, such a wall placement couldn't possibly wall off anything. I mean eliminate from a costly analysis, obviously such a wall placement would be legal by your rules.

Comment: Okay so, I'll try to explain again. There is a 2D matrix that represents the board and between every two squares, there can be a wall (there is always around the borders of the matrix). In the beginning, almost every wall placement is legal, yes, but after some time there is a maze of walls in the grid. Any wall placement that cuts off a path from one of the pawns to one of the goal squares is deemed illegal. The wall placement that doesn't connect to any other wall can't possibly be illegal if that's what you're asking. But my question is for when it connects.